# Transform multiple columns with a function that uses different arguments per column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I write and review a fair amount of R code like this:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:5, 10, rep = TRUE)))
my.func <- function(col, y) {col %in% y}

df$X2 <- my.func(df$X2, c(1,2))
df$X3 <- my.func(df$X3, c(4,5))
df$X5 <- my.func(df$X5, c(1,2))
df$X6 <- my.func(df$X6, c(4,5))
df$X8 <- my.func(df$X8, c(4,5))
df$X9 <- my.func(df$X9, c(1,2))
df$X10 <- my.func(df$X10, c(1))
```

That is, certain columns in a data.frame (or data.table) are transformed using a function, where one argument is a column and the other is some arbitrary, somewhat-unique-to-that-column value.

What's a more concise way to make such transformations?

I've tried using data.table's set (:=) operator, which makes things slightly cleaner, but still each column name must appear twice and the function must appear once for each column.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example along with expected output?

Comment: Added. The output's sort of random here, so I didn't include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's request from a comment:

> make the association between column names and function argument(s) for those columns more explicit

Adjusting the `Map` approach seen in the other answers:

```
yL <- list(X2 = 1:2, X3 = 4:5, X5 = 3:4, X6 = 4:5, X8 = 4:5, X9 = 1:2, X10 = 1)
df[names(yL)] <-  Map(my.func, df[names(yL)], y = yL)
```

With data.table:

```
# this saves you from writing DT twice
DT[, names(yL) := Map(my.func, .SD, y = yL), .SDcols=names(yL)]
```

Answer (score 8):

A concise way would be `Map` with the input arguments as the dataset ('df') and a `list` of `vector` that would be passed as argument to `my.func`.  Here, each column of the data.frame is a `unit` and similarly the vector element from `list`.

```
df[] <- Map(my.func, df, list(1:2, 4:5, 3:4))
```

NOTE: The OP's function or a minimal reproducible example is not provided, so it is not tested

NOTE2: Here, the assumption is that the number of columns is 3.  If it is more than 3, increase the length of the `list` as well

---

The above can also be converted to `data.table` syntax

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, names(df) := Map(my.func, .SD, list(1:2, 4:5, 3:4))]
```

If only a subset of columns needs to be changed, specify the columns in `.SDcols`, and also change the `names(df)` to the subset of names

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2_dfc(df, list(1:2, 4:5, 3:4), my.func)
```

Comment: The solutions here are more concise, but let me challenge you to make the association between column names and function argument(s) for those columns more explicit. Right now, it's unclear that 'col3' gets applied the argument c(3:4), for instance.

Comment: @Emerson. Here, I assume the argument of your function takes care of it.  You haven't provided any example.  So, I don't know

Comment: akrun, thanks for your answer so far. I've modified my example so it's reproducible and illustrates the problem.